# Exception thrown accessing NetHttpBinding endpoint from Portable Library

Tags: c#, wcf, portable-class-library

I need to access a WCF service from a portable library but am getting an exception.

I created a NetHttpBinding using c#:

```
        var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(classType, new Uri("http://localhost:23166/EbmsServices/DataAccess/E21/NET"));
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(endpointInterface, new NetHttpBinding(), "");

        var smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true };
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName, MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

        // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start listening for messages.
        serviceHost.Open();
```

In the client portable library, I added a service reference using Visual Studio.

Here's the code in the portable library:

```
        Service = new DataAccessClient(new NetHttpBinding() { SendTimeout = SendTimeout, ReceiveTimeout = ReceiveTimeout }, new EndpointAddress(ServiceUrl));
        Service.ValidateLoginCompleted += Service_ValidateLoginCompleted;
        Service.ValidateLoginAsync(new ValidateLoginRequest(Guid.NewGuid(), username, password));
```

The service starts up fine and I can access it from non-portable libraries, but when I try this with the portable library I get this exception:

```
        An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll but was not handled in user code

        Additional information: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:23166/EbmsServices/DataAccess/E21/NET that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Inner Exception: 
            Unable to connect to the remote server

Inner Inner Exception:
            No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:23166

What do I need to differently in Portable Libraries to make this work?

For the record, the portable library targets .Net Framework 4.5.1 and Windows 8.1. Also, this did work in a Windows 8.1 App.

Thanks!

Comment: Ensure the service is running by browsing the adress